# PHP: FLV to WMV conversion

Tags: php, flv, wmv

How can I convert FLV to WMV? Is there any script around there or some way I can integrate this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't think there's any pure php converter, you'd probably need to have some application on your server and call it with `system`. Are you allowed to install apps and run `system` on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with PHP.
But, you can use external tools called form PHP (`ffmpeg` for example).

Here is a code sample:

```
<?php

$src = "file.flv";
$output = "file.wmv";
ffmpegPath = "/path/to/ffmpeg";
$flvtool2Path = "/path/to/flvtool2";

$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($src);

$srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());
$srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
$srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();
$srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
$srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();

exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $src . " -ar " . $srcAR . " -ab " . $srcAB . " -vcodec wmv1 -acodec adpcm_ima_wav -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " " . $output. " | " . $flvtool2Path . " -U stdin " . $output);

// Make multiples function
function makeMultipleTwo ($value)
{
$sType = gettype($value/2);
if($sType == "integer")
{
return $value;
} else {
return ($value-1);
}
}
?>
```

Sources:

http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7315615&postcount=10

Answer (score 2):

All solutions [you will find](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20video%20conversion%20) are going to use `ffmpeg`, because that's easy to install on servers and even easier to utilize from PHP scripts. Most always you can just do:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i video.flv video.wmv");
```